# Call procedure inside procedure using dynamic sql modifying the parameters getting passed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to call a procedure inside a procedure and replace all single quotes inside the parameter to double quotes.
Ex: When i call my original proc
begin data(10,'"push's the data"');end;
It throws error due to single quote and i cannot change the string manually at runtime by adding double quote like push''s.
I tried replacing inside procedure but probably because the string is passed first it wont take changes.

I wish to call this procedure inside another and using maybe dynamic sql replace single quotes with double.

Something like this:

```
create procedure dynamic_proc
begin
execute immediate 'begin data(id,'||'replace(string,CHR39,CHR39||CHR39)' AS string)'||' end;'
end;
```

So basically the parameter string which is being passed in procedure data needs to have all single quote replace with double  at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the procedure properly:

```
begin data(10,'"push''s the data"');end;
```

Or use a different quote operator to avoid conflict with single quotes:

```
begin data(10,q'["push's the data"]');end;
```

Comment: How can i call this if the string is getting passed using bind variavle? begin data(10,q'''||:data''');end;'-> something like this doesn't work and includes brackets i am passing in the string.